# Connection pool works when running on eclipse, not working outside of eclipse

Tags: tomcat7, connection-pooling, postgresql-9.1

I created a connection pool.

when starting the server on Eclipse everything works fine
But when I deploy to the webapps folder and then try to run outside of eclipse i can't get  a connection from the connection pool
(I'm getting a nullpointerexception from this line in the servlet code :

```
pstmt  = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

code snippets:

servlet code:

```
Context env = null;


try {

  env = new InitialContext();
  pool = (javax.sql.DataSource) env.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgres");
  conn = pool.getConnection();
```

context.xml

```
    <context>



    <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
           docBase="postgpool" path="/postgpool" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:postgpool"
           scope="Shareable"
        username="postgres" password="789654" maxActive="35" maxIdle="10"
        maxWait="-1" />


    </context>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can be configure tomcat to use one of 3 locations:

1. Use workspace meta-data
2. Use tomcat installation
3. Use custom location

By default, it uses option 1.  Which means it is not using the same context file as the tomcat standalone.  This means eclipse is looking in:

```
$WORKSPACE_ROOT/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX/conf/
```

For its configuration while tomcat standalone will be looking in

```
$TOMCAT_ROOT/conf
```

Assuming you are using application context files and your app is named `myapp` you will need to ensure your context file is properly deployed to:

```
$TOMCAT_ROOT/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml
```

If your war file contains `/META-INF/context.xml` it *should* get automatically deployed as `$TOMCAT_ROOT/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml` when you place the war in the tomcat webapps folder.  However, there have been bugs where this does not happen, so you may still have to copy by hand

Comment: when running on eclipse I was able to locate the server.xml at :

     $WORKSPACE_ROOT/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX/conf/ 
file.

after copying the <context> from that server.xml into the standalone server.xml the connection worked fine
no xml file was generated at     $TOMCAT_ROOT/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml
and copying the context.xml file to that folder didn't help either.


I'm guessing something is wrong with my context config I just don't understand what exactly